# Formula for expectation in terms inverse function

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a r.v. with distribution function $F$ and inverse $F^{-1}$.
I have to show that $\displaystyle E(X)=\int^1_0 F^{-1}(t)  dt$.

Well, for a well defined expected value, we have $\displaystyle E(X)=\int^{\infty}_0 (1-F(x)) dx - \int_{-\infty}^0F(x)dx$.

I've tried to use the subtitution method to solve the integral, but somehow I do not seem to obtain  what I must show...

Is this not the right way to think about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=F'(x)$ is the probability density function, then

$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx.$$

Use the change of variables $u = F(x)$. Then $x = F^{-1}(u)$ and we have

$$du = F'(x)dx = f(x) dx,\\\ dx = \frac1{f[F^{-1}(u)]}du.$$

Hence,

$$E(X) = \int_{0}^{1}F^{-1}(u)f[F^{-1}(u)]\frac1{f[F^{-1}(u)]}du = \int_{0}^{1}F^{-1}(u)du $$

Comment: By the way, how would you prove this same assertion, if the r.v. was discrete valued?

Comment: If $P(X= x_k )=p_k$ with $x_k$ increasing, then $E(X) = \sum x_kp_k$ and the df is $P(X \leq x_k)=F_k= \sum_{j=1}^{k}p_j$. Then the expected value is $E(X) = \sum x_k(F_k-F_{k-1})=\sum (x_k-x_{k+1})F_k$. I'm not sure how to carry the analogy further.

Answer (score 2):

If $X\geqslant0$ almost surely then
$$F^{-1}(t)=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{s\lt F^{-1}(t)}\mathrm ds=\int_0^\infty\mathbf 1_{F(s)\lt t}\mathrm ds$$
hence
$$\int^1_0 F^{-1}(t)\mathrm dt=\int_0^\infty\int_0^1\mathbf 1_{F(s)\lt t}\mathrm dt\mathrm ds=\int_0^\infty\int_{F(s)}^1\mathrm dt\mathrm ds=\int_0^\infty(1-F(s))\,\mathrm ds,
$$
that is,
$$
\int^1_0 F^{-1}(t)\mathrm dt=E(X).
$$

Comment: Thanks @Did, but I cannot assume that X is nonnegative.